# Width set in rem not scaling responsively as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a responsive page using rem unit for the first time. I have my root html font-size set to 16 px and I have set container width 80 rem.

```
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 80rem;
}
```

My understanding is that 80rem should be 80 * 16px = 1280px.

But when I resize the browser the container width stays fixed at 1280px and doesn't scale down responsively.

What am I missing here? I thought using pixel font-size on html was the right approach for responsive scaling with rem?

Answer (score 0):

The `font-size: 16px` doesn't change when you resize the browser, hence the container width is always equal to `1280px`.
If you want to change the container width based on browser resize, then you need to use `vw` which is based on viewport.
Below is how you can have your container element to be always 80% of viewport.

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw;
}
```

if you still want to use rem then you need to change the root font-size based on browser resize.

```css
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 80rem;
}
```

Comment: Saying you *need* to use `vw` to change the width of an element based on the browser width  is patently wrong and your answer contradicts itself.

Comment: Oh I see. I understood rem responsiveness the wrong way. Thanks for clarifying. I still need to use media queries and specify root element size for different screen sizes. Also, I have very limited knowledge about vw vh units and for this excercise I have to create responsive page using rem.

Comment: I have a follow up question, so I got the whole web page ready. It just needs to be made responsive now and change size of all the elements to rem from px. 

I made it this way because it was getting hard for me to determine the sizes in rem, as I am not used to it. So, I decided to design with the sizes in px initially and then convert to rems.

I have added media queries and assigned root element size as 20, 18 and 16 for different breakpoints (are they okay?), but I need to convert all those values now. 

Is there a smarter/quicker way to do it? I am using visual studio code.

Comment: vh and vw are similar to percentages. But the difference is that vh and vw depend on the viewport of the device and percentages depend on the parent element. For example width: 50vw, always occupies 50% of the screen. but width: 50%, always occupies 50% of its parent element. Generally for containers, I use vw and vh. For example, I want a container to occupy like 70% of the width on desktop and 90% in mobile device. I would do something like this,
`desktop
  .container {
    width: 70vw
  } 
mobile
  .container {
    width: 90vw
  } `

Comment: if you really want to change each and every `px` to `rem` on vsc, then you can just click on the search icon and enter px in search field and rem in replace field and click on replace button next to it. Also make sure to select match whole word and match case. But note that this only replace the units and not values. Also this might replace any matching case in js files as well so be careful while doing it. I am not aware of any methods that can automatically calculate the values as well.

Answer (score 0):

REM is a relative unit to the root aka `<html>` tag. So if you set the `font-size:16px` in `.html` and give `font-size:1rem` to `.p` then size of text in `<p>` would be equivalent to `16px`.

- REM helps create responsive pages easily as you can adjust the size of every element on the page by changing just the font-size in root element. Though, you still have to use the media queries to set font-size of `<html>` for different viewports.
- REM also helps you create pages with better accessibility features. For instance, you can add a slider on the web page that adjusts the root font size and in turn makes the design, fonts, everything bigger to make it easy to see/read for visually impaired people.

So, this is how REM works. Below is the code for your information:

```css
/* For Desktop */
@media (min-width: 993px) {
  html {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

/* For tablet */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  html {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

/* For Mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 80rem;
}
```

Answering your follow up question:

I understand it is a bit mind bogging, especially when you are just starting to give sizes in em/rem in CSS. But with time you'll learn it.

Now that you have the web page ready with all sizes in px, below are few ways you can change and convert all px values to rem.

1. Easiest way for you: You can install vscode plugin called pixel to rem (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sainoba.px-to-rem) which lets you easily select and convert values by pressing alt+z
2. Easy but a bit time consuming way: You can use online px to rem converters (https://cssunitconverter.com/px-to-rem/) and copy paste the values.
3. Advanced but a fun and learning way: Using Sass, create a px-to-rem mixin that handles the conversion based on a $root-font-size variable (tutorial - https://dev.to/nikolab/convert-px-to-rem-using-sass-3-methods-4ep2).